# Database connectivity error with EE on Network Solutions

Tags: database, error

I'm setting up a staging server on a Network Solutions site before preparing it to go live next week. I created a new subdomain pointing to /htdocs/staging/html so I can move system above root (plan to do the same to the live site; /htdocs/live/html). However I'm getting the infamous error message:

`An Error Was Encountered
Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; No Preferences Found`

I've double checked the database settings and the tried using both the server alias and IP address. Username and passsword for MySQL have been checked and double checked. I'm sure someone has successfully hosted an EE site on Network Solutions and can hopefully give me an idea of what I might be doing wrong here.

Comment: If you set debug in your config file to "2" does it give you any additional info?

Comment: Turned out to be a bone-headed move on my part. I was editing the dev config file. On a side note, I can't wait to get this project over with.

Comment: @StuartMcCoy Can you post your solution as an answer so it gets archived... You can select it as the correct answer to your question in a couple days as well.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to edit the correct file. I had my config file from the local dev site open instead of the staging site.